# views export to xls

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I need to export views into xls file. If I use any of possible modules like views bonus or views xls export, I get a simple file with xls extension but inside is clean html code of the table instead of a compiled code as excell would produce. I can load it into excell and save it as proper xls file but is there a straight solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module? Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... designed to provide a way to export large amounts of data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support exporting in the following types:
>
> - CSV.
> - Microsoft XLS.
> - Microsoft DOC.
> - Basic TXT.
> - XML.
>
> This module also exposes a drush command that can execute the view and save its results to a file.

Comment: yes I did, I use it now. But the outcome is the same - html code inside a xls file.

Comment: I've just found this:
[Why are the XLS/DOC export files just HTML tables?](http://drupal.org/node/1820458)

Depending on your needs you may export to CSV, this format is easily imported into Excel.